# How can I open an email in Gmail Web Client, but in "Safe mode", with tracking images deactivated?

Tags: gmail

Supposed I get an email which was **not** marked by Gmail as potential spam/suspicious, but I would like to open it **with any potential tracking image inside it deactivated** (eg: *tracker pixels in iframes, that notify the sender that the email was opened*).

***THE SAME WAY way Outlook desktop client does*** when you receive an email from somebody outside the organization which is not in your contacts list...

Is there any way to achieve this in Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about image tracking. It's where the senders use an image of 1x1 size. Once loaded it can't seen be but it logs you in the image's server.

To bypass it you can make your entire Gmail account [disable **all** images by default](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919):

[image: Disable all images]

Comment: Hey, I've see other trackers as well, some based on <iframe> with size zero. Any ideas about those ?

Comment: Don't think it's possible. Any chance you know such a tracker in order to actually try it and see how Gmail reacts?